# Default values of PATH variable

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

After searching all over the internet, I came know where to alter the values of PATH variable in case of interactive/non-interactive - login/non-login shell combinations.

Found from another post

https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/

I have "/bin/sh" as default login shell and only /etc/profile file is being used to export all needed environment variables in my system. And in case of non-interactive login shell, /etc/profile is not being referred too, even though above link says it would. But still when I execute,

```
ssh -4 -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@xxxx "env"
Password:
SHELL=/bin/sh
...
**PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin**
...
```

I could see some default values for PATH variable. I would like to know where exactly these default values of PATH are being set.

Answer (score 1):

**You should not care at all where `PATH` is set.** You should set `PATH` always in your shell startup file (`.profile` or `.bashrc`).

This way you do not rely on someone else's soon useless assumption what directories should be in your `PATH`. The only one who knows is YOU.

Start out with

```
PATH=$(getconf PATH)
```

and then add to your liking with

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
PATH=$PATH:<...any other directory you need...>
```

PS: In your specific case, it looks like the `PATH` is inherited from the remote end's SSH daemon which eventually forks your shell. If a shell does not inherit a `PATH` from its parent, it will set a default value that you can query with `env -i /bin/sh -c 'echo $PATH'`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But again, I was curious to know where this default PATH was set. I am sure, its not from remote end`s SSH daemon. I did it from my development environment to production environment. Development environment has very huge PATH value, most of it are NA in production environment. I tried your second alternative also. Even that has something more than what I pasted :(

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your distribution.  In Debian and its derivatives, the definition is found in `/etc/environment` and it is read into the current session by inclusion of `pam_env.so` in the appropriate `/etc/pam.d/` files.